# How to find the expectation and the standard deviation about this question?

Tags: probability

According to the observation, 80% customers order breakfast A, while other customers order breakfast B. At this moment, all six tables in the cafe are occupied, each table with one customer.
Then the question is :breakfast A is cost $45 while breakfast B is cost 38 dollar. What is the expectation and the standard deviation of the revenue for repeated samples of six individual customers?

Answer (score 0):

Every customer can order either A or B with probability 0.8 or 0.2 respectively (lets call these $p_A$ and $p_B = 1 - p_A$). The cost of A is \$45 and B is \$38 (call these $r_A$ and $r_B$).

Expected value of revenue from one customer (say $r/c$) is,
$$E[r/c] = (p_A \times r_A) + (p_B \times r_B)$$
$$E[r/c] = (p_A \times r_A) + ((1-p_A) \times r_B)$$

Expected revenue from 6 customers is just 6 times the expression above. This is also the mean revenue from 6 customers (let's call this $\mu$).

As for the standard deviation, it is,
\begin{equation}
\sigma = \sqrt{Var(r)}
\end{equation}

where,
$$Var(r) = \left(\sum Pr(r = r_i) \times r_i^2 \right) - \mu^2$$

Now for a single customer $r_i$ could only be either $r_A$ or $r_B$, but for 6 customers, there are $2^6$ different permutations of meals that can be generated for a given set of customers.

However, if $n_A$ customers chose A and $n_B = 6 - n_A$ customers chose B, then the revenue generated is $n_A \times r_A + (6-n_A) \times r_B$. As $n_A$ can be anywhere between 0 (no customer chose A) to 6 (all of them chose A). The probability that $n_A$ will choose A and $6-n_A$ choose B is $p_A^{n_A} (1-p_A)^{6-n_A}$.

$$Var(r) = \left(\sum_{n_A = 0}^{6} p_A^{n_A} (1-p_A)^{6-n_A} (n_A \times r_A + (6-n_A) \times r_B)^2 \right) - \mu^2$$

Use this to get the standard deviation.